# How do I change password on Pokémon go

Tags: pokemon-go

Can't figure out how to change password on Pokémon go. Any help would be great. Thank you .

Comment: This question is falsely marked as duplicate. The other question is about *recovering* your password after you lost it. This one is about *changing* it.

Answer (score 3):

Pokemon Go doesn't have a password for the application itself. You will need to change the passwords for either your Google or Pokemon Trainer Club account, whichever you use to login. There is no way to do either of those within the app though.

You can login to [Google](https://accounts.google.com/login) or [Pokemon Trainer Club](https://sso.pokemon.com/sso/login?locale=en&service=https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/caslogin) and change the passwords there.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options depending on your account type.

- Trainer Club: [here](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/my-password) (or log in [here](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/) and click on your user name. In the following menu is a *Change Password* button.
- Google A: Change the password of your Google account [here](https://myaccount.google.com/security?utm_source=OGB#signin). This will change the password of *all* apps and devices associated with that account, unless you're using app passwords (see next option).
- Google B: If you have an app password or want one: click [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords), select app and device and generate one. This only works for apps you authorized to use your GMail account.

Comment: +1 for adding a direct link to the password change page of the trainer club. Looks like it's under maintenance atm though.